# I have this function, I want the addresses and phones to be an array of objects not an object all dynamically, any solution please?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nested, nested-object

[the display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewtjR.png)
and this is the function:

```
const [fields, setFields] = useState<any[]>([]);

 const handleInputChanges = (
   value: string,
    level?: any,
   fieldName?: string,
   subName?: string
  ) => {
    if (!level) {
      setFields({
       ...fields,
       [fieldName ? fieldName : ""]: value,
     });
   } else {
      setFields((fields) => {
        let newSubField = {
         ...fields,

          [level]: {
           ...fields[level],
           [subName ? subName : ""]: value,
          },
        };
        return newSubField;
      });
   }
  };
```